# Windows FONDUE - how is it triggered?

Tags: windows, installshield

Windows sometimes prompts "An app on your PC needs the following Windows feature" which, per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29551954/how-to-show-an-app-on-your-pc-needs-the-following-windows-feature-dialog-prog) (among others) is shown by "fondue.exe". For example, if an app that uses .Net 3.5 is installed on a Windows 8 or 10 machine, fondue.exe is somehow invoked which prompts the user to install that .Net version.

I'm interested in knowing *how* fondue is invoked in this circumstance. Hours of searching and rephrasing the search terms has not been fruitful.

A corollary question: is it possible in an installer (InstallShield) to *disable* this check?

Answer (score 0):

There are two fundamental approaches I believe are possible. I don't know which is correct.

- Windows recognizes .NET executables specially. As part of launching a process, it could examine the executable, realize it targets a version of the CLR that is not installed, and prompt via fondue to install that version of the CLR.
- Part of loading a .NET executable and in particular the right version of the CLR all goes through a central point such as mscorlib.dll. As part of this loading process, if the target version of the CLR is not available, it could launch and wait for fondue.

As for how to avoid this, I see two options:

- Preemptively install the required version of the .NET framework. In general this gets difficult because sometimes it requires a redistributable, sometimes it requires enabling a Windows feature, and sometimes that feature is not locally available.
- Configure the .NET executable to support using later versions of the CLR. Typically a later version of .NET is present when fondue is shown. Do this by adding the [supportedRuntime element](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w4atty68.aspx) to the [.exe.config](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj152935.aspx) file. If possible, it's better for the development team to do this rather than the installation team, as there are backwards compatibility reasons that this option is not enabled by default.

Comment: I'm actually one of the devs on the project in question. We have a "Free" version that on Win 8/10 triggers Fondue asking for .Net 3.5, but we don't believe that it's actually required (we compile against 4.6.1.) I think I'll give the "supportedRuntime" idea a try to see if we can massage the installer into thinking that we're good with just 4.6.1. I'll post back when I know more. Thanks!